# Ember model rollback prevents me from setting properties

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have a model that's being created in a parent route.

```
App.ParentRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  model: -> @store.createRecord('banana')
```

When I hit a certain child route of the parent route, I'd like for all unsaved changed to the model to be dropped.

```
App.ChildRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  afterModel: (banana) -> banana.rollback()
```

The problem is once `rollback` is called, Ember won't allow me to set properties on it. When I try, I get this error:

```
Error: Attempted to handle event `didSetProperty` on <App.Banana:ember296:null> while in state root.deleted.saved. Called with {name: color, oldValue: undefined, originalValue: undefined, value: yellow}.
```

I read this could be due to some kind of observer on the object, but I don't have any observers set up. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was fixed in Ember Data 1.0 beta 8, https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/v1.0.0-beta.8/CHANGELOG.md and is available here http://builds.emberjs.com/tags/v1.0.0-beta.8/ember-data.js

Comment: Hmm, I still seem to be getting this with 1.0.0-beta8.

Comment: Hmm, I remember the pull request for that particular issue, and now that I look at it I might be wrong... https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/1648#issuecomment-32109371  Did you actually save or delete the record before calling rollback (I'm trying to replicate)?

Comment: Nope, no saving or deleting.

Comment: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/581/edit change, rollback, change again... looks like a rollback bug. I'll hunt a bit more, but I'm guessing we'll need to manually change the state back to uncommitted after the rollback and submit a PR.

Comment: I took a look at `store.js` in the Ember Data repository and tried to figure out what might be going on, but honestly I'm a little lost. I'd be happy to pitch in if you could point me in the right direction.

Comment: from what I've gathered, the concept of rolling back reverts the record to a previously committed state, but an uncommitted record doesn't have that, so whether or not rolling an uncommitted record back may or may not make a ton of sense.  You can just destroy the record and create a new one to get back to a default uncommitted state.

Comment: I think there's a bit of a mismatch between the documentation and the implementation. "If the model isDirty this function will discard any unsaved changes." Ideally, it would clear out the changes on an uncommitted model without the state change. In terms of state change, `rollback` would transition from `"uncommitted"` to `"uncommitted"`. How is the state managed inside of `DS.Model`? Is there a state machine managing these interactions?

Comment: yes there is a state machine handling the different states, https://github.com/emberjs/ember-states/tree/master/packages/ember-states/lib  and https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/packages/ember-data/lib/system/model/states.js

Comment: I guess the most basic implementation would be rollback from uncommitted where record is `isNew` would just blast away all properties making it a new record.

Comment: Makes sense. Should I try a pull request?

Comment: yeah, try away, I can see some argument when someone tries to create a record and sends in properties, would that record revert to empty, or to it's initial value, but there's no way to keep track of that information now.